# Python variable losing type information after first iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a simple algorithm in Python to print all permutations of a given list of elements but am encountering an error that I am not able to debug:

```
def perm(prefix, rest):
    if len(rest) == 0:
        print prefix 
    print len(rest)
    for i in range(len(rest)):
        #The next 3 prints are for debugging purposes only
        print type(prefix)
        print "prefix=", prefix
        print "rest=", rest
        newprefix = prefix.append( rest[i])
        newrest = rest
        newrest.pop(i)
        perm(newprefix, newrest)


perm([], ['a','b','c'])
```

For some reason my variable 'prefix' changes to a type None after the first iteration of my for loop. And here's the output I get:

```
3
<type 'list'>
prefix= []
rest= ['a', 'b', 'c']
2
<type 'NoneType'>
prefix= None
rest= ['b', 'c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "self2.py", line 19, in <module>
    perm([], ['a','b','c'])
  File "self2.py", line 16, in perm
    perm(newprefix, newrest)
  File "self2.py", line 13, in perm
    newprefix = prefix.append( rest[i])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.append` changes the list in-place and returns `None`. So after this step `newprefix` is actually `None`.

```
newprefix = prefix.append( rest[i])
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the lines

```
newprefix = prefix.append( rest[i])
perm(newprefix, newrest)
```

`append` returns `None`, and you then pass `None` to the next call of your `perm` method because `newprefix` has been set to `None`.

Perhaps you want

```
prefix.append(rest[i])
newprefix = prefix
```

However if this is the case, you can change your `perm` call to `perm(prefix, newrest)` and you don't need `newprefix` at all.